# Android LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates emits the same location even device moved significantly

Tags: android, gps, location, locationmanager, android-gnss

I am requesting location updates using `LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates` using the GPS provider. I am requesting updates every second. We have a foreground service running to make sure that we get consistent location updates even when the app is in background.

We did test runns with multiple devices and we discovered something very interesting. The location would "freeze" on some devices which means that `onLocationChanged` is called but it always reports  an outdated location. This location has the exact same lat/long values, **but it has a new timestamp** which is incorrect.
Other devices continued to record the location correctly.
All devices where running the same app/code.

Has anybody experienced similar issues before and knows what the problem is ?

I expected all devices to behave the same.

Comment: new timestamp incorrect, which mean, like late timestamp?

Comment: The timestamp is updated and I always get a newer timestamp that is not older then a few seconds.
However the position is clearly outdated because the position is the same, this is why I said it was incorrect.

Comment: Did you resolve this? I'm experiencing the exact same thing. I've only seen it on Samsung S21 5G devices running Android 13. It started sometime in the last six months. Was perfect before then. Battery Optimization set to Unrestricted, all the usual battery stuff disabled.

Comment: @BradStiff No, we don't have a solution to this problem yet. The issue disappeared and its not happening anymore for 2 months.
We saw this issue happening mostly on samsung devices, but we also saw this happening on a pixel phone once

Comment: @JulianLenz Were any changes made that may have contributed to the issue disappearing? Did you try using the Fused Location Provider API by chance, and if so, any comments on one versus the other for continuous location updates? I'm using LocationManager.

Comment: The issues started to appear again, so the answer is no :/ 
Right now FusedLocationProvider is not an option for my use case but its defently worth trying it out if it works for you